# The largest possible $m$ so that you are guaranteed to have a blue copy of $K_m$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a complete graph on $25$ vertices with each edge coloured red or blue. If there are no red triangles, what is the largest possible $m$ so that you are guaranteed to have a blue copy of $K_m$?

I tried using Ramsey's Theorem but could not proceed. Need some help in this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know Ramsey theory ...

**Hint:** $R(3,7) = 23. R(3,8) = 28$

So the answer is $m=7$.

---

If you're not allowed to quote the result, find a way to show that $ R(3,7) \leq 25$, likely by induction on:

$$R(k, l) \leq \begin{cases} R(k-1,l) + R(k, l-1) -1 & \text{if } R(k-1,l), R(k, l-1) \text{are both even}    \\ R(k-1,l) + R(k, l-1)  & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$